# Проблемы с простым проектом с Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Пытаюсь написать приложение по https://www.toptal.com/spring/beginners-guide-to-mvc-with-spring-framework
Запускается успешно, но на localhost пишет:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Как исправить ее в данном проекте?

В HTML в строке по типу

```html
<tr th:each="student : ${students}">
```

> students

выделяется как ошибка. Почему?

К

Comment: Недостаточно информации, чтобы помочь вам. Есть ли что-нибудь в консоли? Приведите кусок кода из контроллера из вью.

Comment: Дополнил. В консоли вроде ошибок нет. у каждого сообщения пометка INFO.

Comment: определён ли  namespace для th?  (xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org")
Опять же  - подключен ли thymeleaf корректно?

Comment: Как определить корректность подключения thymeleaf?

Comment: Проверьте, что возвращает `studentRepository.findAll()`. Попробуйте запустить в режиме отладки (добавьте `debug: false` в `application.properties`), чтобы увидеть больше сообщений в логе. Ваш проект где-нибудь доступен (в смысле ишодный код)?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin залил на git

Comment: Для истории: конечно же надо было добавить `debug: true`, а не `debug: false` :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема #1: на `/` ничего не замаплено, поэтому при открытии сайта вы видите подобную ошибку.

Проблема #2: если обратиться по адресу `/students`, то появляется еще одна ошибка, но уже другая: `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "student.forename + ' ' + student.surame" (students:16)`. Если очень внимательно посмотреть, то уже ясно в чем дело, но на всякий случай можно посмотреть в консоль на исключение: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 33): Property or field 'surame' cannot be found on object of type 'wenti.entity.Student' - maybe not public?`
Причина в банальной опечатке -- вы обращаетесь к полю `surame`, вместо `surname`.

Answer (score 2):

При работе `Spring Boot` + `Freemarker` если появляется страница:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

В версии `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.1.RELEASE` не работает `freemarker`:

1. переименуйте файлы `Freemarker` c `.ftl` на `.ftlh`
2. Добавьте в `application.properties`:

   `spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true`
   `spring.freemarker.suffix= .ftl`

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1051087) о том, что:

При работе Spring Boot + Freemarker если появляется страница:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

У меня версия spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.3 чтобы  работал freemarker сделал следующее:

Добавьте в ваш файл application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=file:src/main/resources/templates/ 
spring.freemarker.suffix: .ftl
```

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке написано, что неверный мапинг по адресу `/error`. Spring перенаправляет вас на страницу `/error` когда по вашему GET запросу произошла ошибка на сервере.

Какие есть варианты
 1. Ошибка при получении/обработке данных на сервере (как пример `NullPointerException`). Пройтись дебагом по коду, посмотреть не выпадает ли где exception.
 2. Ошибка при парсинге страницы thymeleaf.

Посмотрите лог, скорее всего ваша ошибка выше, чем то, что вы указали в отрывке.

Comment: При запуске в выводе нет строк ERROR, только INFO. Как проверить ошибки при парсинге страницы?